# How to fetch limited rows from a table using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table,lets say Transaction and it has few columns and the data look like this:

Id  ------- Amount ------- Isvoid ----------- ImpactId

1 -------- 300.00 ----------  0---------------- NULL

2 -------- 500.00 ----------  0---------------- NULL

This shows the data inserted when a transaction happens.

Now when a void of any particular transaction happens,a new row is inserted and Isvoid is 1 for that row and ImpactId is the Id of that respective transaction which is voided.

Lets say Amount 500.00 is voided and the table looks this:

Id  ------- Amount ------- Isvoid ----------- ImpactId

1 -------- 300.00 ----------  0---------------- NULL

2 -------- 500.00 ----------  0---------------- NULL

3 -------- 500.00 ----------  1----------------- 2

Now i want to retrieve rows only which are not voided.

Iam trying to write the query in Linq like following,but it is showing all the records.

```
from t in Context.Transaction.Where(t => t.Isvoid == false && t.ImpactID != null)
```

I want transactions only which are not voided.

How to write for the same in Linq.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if `t.Isvoid == false` (or `!t.Isvoid`) doesn't do it, we can't tell what's going on. Looks like it should work. Look at the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you voiding transactions, the transactions they voided, and the rest (I think)

```
class Program
{
private Model1 model = new Model1();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.Run();

    var what = System.Console.ReadLine();
}

public void Run()
{
    var voiding = this.model.Transactions
        .Where(t => t.IsVoid)
        .ToList();

    System.Console.WriteLine("Voiding transactions: ");
    this.PrintTransactions(voiding);

    var voided = this.model.Transactions
        .Where(t => t.IsVoid)
        .Join(this.model.Transactions.AsEnumerable(),
            t1 => t1.ImpactId,
            t2 => t2.Id,
            (t1, t2) => t2)
        .ToList();

    System.Console.WriteLine("Voided transactions: ");
    this.PrintTransactions(voided);

    var notVoided = this.model.Transactions
        .Except(this.model.Transactions
            .Where(t => t.IsVoid)
            .Join(this.model.Transactions.AsEnumerable(),
                t1 => t1.ImpactId,
                t2 => t2.Id,
                (t1, t2) => t2))
        .Where(t => !t.IsVoid)
        .ToList();

    System.Console.WriteLine("The rest: ");
    this.PrintTransactions(notVoided);
}

private void PrintTransactions(ICollection<Transaction> transaction)
{
    transaction.ToList()
        .ForEach(t =>
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", t.Id, t.Amount, t.IsVoid, t.ImpactId));
        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You wrote the value of the IsVoid as a number the query need to be like that:

```
from t in Context.Transaction.Where(t => t.Isvoid != 1 && t.ImpactID == null)
```

But if you wrote it as boolean it suppose to be like that:

```
from t in Context.Transaction.Where(t => t.Isvoid == false && t.ImpactID == null)
```

Answer (score 1):

The impactID *should* be **null** in cases where the transactions is *not* void, change last part of your query to use == instead of !=

```
from t in Context.Transaction.Where(t => t.Isvoid == false && t.ImpactID == null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have accepted an answer bu there is an easy way to get not voided transactions.

```
var notVoided = Transactions.Where( t => t.ImpactId == null 
                && !Transactions.Any( t2 => t2.ImpactId == t.Id));
```